# how to enable PUT method in Jetty?

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js, jetty

I'm working on a Spring REST / Backbone application.

While GET works great, I'm having trouble with PUT (and probably the same with DELETE).

My Spring controller has the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void putItem( @PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Item item) {...}
```

But when I try to save a Backbone model, I get the following error:

```
405 (HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL)
```

The GET mapping is in the same controller class and uses the same url annotation (class-level).

Are my annotations correct? I'm using Jetty for server, do I need to configure it somehow to allow PUT requests?

EDIT:

assuming that this is a Jetty configuration issue, I added the following to webdefault.xml

```
<web-resource-collection>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  <http-method>GET</http-method>
  <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
  <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
```

inside the `<security-constraint>` definition. It has the effect that now GET method returns 403 (Forbidden) -- so it's as if this definition would be indeed only constrain the security and is not the means of making it more liberal. I also tried removing the GET and PUT lines but it had no effect on my orginal 405 error (of course it did make GET work again)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that GET POST PUT and DELETE verbs are enabled on the server. Your problem is not client side, so if you have access to server settings just make sure the above verbs are enabled. I am not familiar with jetty, but it looks as though it is not supported out of the box and would require some sort of your own handler. Here is the resource that I found after doing a quick search -> [JETTY - PUT DELETE](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jetty.support/14965)

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured out that the problem was the *.do pattern.

Backbone was adding the .do before the pathvariable, hence it didn't work. I got rid of the postfix entirely and now it works!

Comment: why would backbone add a .do to anything? that looks like something custom